# issues with file writing in twincat 3 on beckhoff CX8190

Tags: file, logging, twincat

I try to log data in TwinCAT 3 ST language. Beckhoff documentation is IMO a bit incomplete.
When I try to save txt file and read it using preinstalled notepad (in windows CE 7.0 its called notepadce) I see that notepad read the file and an error window appeared (failed to open document)
[Tryin to open a text document foobar01.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJf2i.png)

Could you look at the code and show me where is the mistake? Or maybe you have better tutorial of file handling than Beckhoff Information System?

Code below:

```
//declarations of variables
PROGRAM MAIN
VAR
    nStage          :   INT :=0;
    fbFileOpen      :   FB_FileOpen;    // open or create file
    fbFileWrite     :   FB_FileWrite;    // write to file
    fbFileClose     :   FB_FileClose;   // Close file

    sPath           :   STRING  :=  '\temp\foobar01.txt';    // target path
    sAmsNetID       :   STRING  := '5.109.203.84.1.1';
    
    nVariable       :   INT := 0;
    
    bWriteError     :   BOOL;
    bOpenError      :   BOOL;
    
    sDataToWrite    :   STRING:='All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy';
    
    nErrId          :   UDINT   :=  0;
    bError          :   BOOL    :=  FALSE;
    hDataFileRefnum :   UINT    :=  0;
END_VAR

//-----end of declaration, main code-----

CASE nStage OF
    0:  fbFileOpen(bExecute := FALSE);
        fbFileOpen  (
                    sNetId := '',
                    sPathName := sPath,
                    nMode := FOPEN_MODEWRITE OR FOPEN_MODETEXT,
                    ePath := PATH_GENERIC,
                    bExecute := TRUE
                    );
        nInc(nStage);
    
    1:  fbFileOpen(bExecute := FALSE);
        IF fbFileOpen.bBusy = FALSE AND fbFileOpen.bError = TRUE THEN
            nErrId  :=  fbFileOpen.nErrId;
            bError  :=  TRUE;
            nStage  :=  10;
        END_IF;
        IF fbFileOpen.bBusy = FALSE AND fbFileOpen.bError = FALSE THEN
            hDataFileRefnum := fbFileOpen.hFile;
            nInc(nStage);
        END_IF;
    2:  fbFileWrite( bExecute := FALSE);
        fbFileWrite (
                        sNetId      :=  sAmsNetId,
                        hFile       :=  hDataFileRefnum,
                        pWriteBuff  :=  ADR(sDataToWrite),
                        cbWriteLen  :=  SIZEOF(sDataToWrite),
                        bExecute    :=  TRUE
                    );
        nInc(nStage);
 
    3:  fbFileWrite(bExecute := FALSE); 
        IF fbFileWrite.bBusy = FALSE AND fbFileWrite.bError = TRUE THEN
            nErrId  :=  fbFileWrite.nErrId;
            bError  :=  TRUE;
            nStage  :=  10;
        END_IF
        IF fbFileWrite.bBusy = FALSE AND fbFileWrite.bError = FALSE THEN
            nInc(nStage);
        END_IF
    4:  fbFileClose( bExecute := FALSE);
        fbFileClose( sNetId := sAmsNetID, hFile := hDataFileRefnum, bExecute:=TRUE);
        IF fbFileClose.bBusy = FALSE AND fbFileClose.bError = TRUE THEN
            nErrid  :=  fbFileClose.nErrId;
            bError  :=  TRUE;
            nStage  :=  10;
        END_IF
        IF fbFileClose.bBusy = FALSE AND fbFileClose.bError = FALSE THEN
            fbFileClose.hFile   :=  0;
            nStage  :=  9;
        END_IF
    9:  (*Normal ending*)   
        nStage := nStage;
    10: nErrId;
        bError; 
END_CASE
```

Comment: I see the text which you tried to write in the document. So you can open the document, the content is in there, but you still get the error?

Comment: I remember having similar issues trying to open the text files that my PLC wrote in Windows CE OS. I can't remember what I ended up doing or what the cause was. Can you try and read the file from some other system, maybe your engineering PC via FTP maybe? I think that the issue didn't show when trying to read it from there. https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/sw_os/6823361035.html&id=

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine on my local PC - I open the file with notepad with no issues. I am pretty sure its a bug with notepad or something silly with Windows CE 7.

Comment: Ok. I Solved the problem!
I run FTP on Beckhoff's CX8910 and found that problem was with many NULL characters after text.
I saw this in PC in Notepad++. NotepadCE doesn't see non printable characters and this is why it say that file is corrupted.
So If you ever had this issue, turn off or configure Firewall in CX8190 for using FTP, then download it for PC and then check if there are non-printable characters.

Thanks a lot for help! Best Regards

Comment: Great :) I ended up using USB as the storage device there since HMI is very uncinfortable for viewing logs. Thanks for the heads up.